# How to fix Total compatibility with doxygen and github-page

Tags: travis-ci, doxygen, github-pages

I try to link the doxygen documentation and the github-page, I have found the method with the travis-ci ([here](https://gist.github.com/bmegli/e22ba525dda0b197b2d4440d08f43ae2)) but the "_" file doesn't work...

No worry there is two hack found [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing)
with the .nojekyll method it works but now mathematical formulas are no longer transformed with mathjax....
I try to add a short _config.yml with :

```
include: 
  - "_*.html"
```

Same thing i add in the config file in case of

```
markdown: kramdown
```

Same thing

Of course [my repository](https://github.com/tmonseigne/Riemann-Geometrie)

If you have a solution Ty.

Comment: I'm not completely getting what is missing in the doxygen part. Can you create a small example that shows in doxygen what is missing? Also specify which doxygen version you are using.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to link the result directly
[Example page generated with mathematical formula](https://tmonseigne.github.io/Riemann-Geometrie/class_c_matrix_classifier_m_d_m.html#a4170211dbb5034b0996a6612681211ab)
and travis CI use doxygen (1.8.11-1) on ubuntu Xenial [Travis result](https://travis-ci.org/tmonseigne/Riemann-Geometrie)

Comment: The version 1.8.11 is a bit old (December 2015), current version is 1.8.15. This is not the source of the problem though. I think that the problem is that the javascript is blocked at the site. When I save the page locally, show it in the browser and scroll (!! not jump through a link as the link goes again to the site) to the classify method I see the formulas. So solution is either have the javascript enabled on the site (will probably also refuses to show the treeview when `GENERATE_TREEVIEW=YES`) or not to use MathJax but generate formulas by means of Latex  (just disable MathJax).

Comment: Ty albert for your answer (and time) but it's not the problem I think.^^ I added the treeview to test, it works. I don't find the option to use latex for mathematical formula in HTML Build....

Comment: You use MathJax for the formulas, so you set `USE_MATHJAX=YES` by setting it to `NO` the LaTeX rendering will be used (during the generation of the doxygen pages so you will need a LaTeX distribution).

Comment: Thank you albert, It's really ugly with pixellated latex images but it works. As long as I can not get Matjax to use github-page, that will be enough.

Comment: Indeed the LaTeX formula images are not very nice. Maybe you should post in the MathJax forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) or on a github forum or here on stackoverflow with tags github, mathjax,  javascript) a question regarding using MathJax on github pages